# Object to input the keyboard characters and numbers and dispaly the output in a text field in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am using NSMutableString object to read input digits from keypad. It is becoming cumbersome with some complex arithmetic operations using this object. Is there any other way to read the input data and display the data in a textfiled?

Below is the code currently being used.

```
digit = (int)sender.tag;
[displayString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", digit]];
display.text = displayString;
currentnumber = currentnumber*10 + digit;
```

Comment: What's complex about the code you posted?

Comment: There is no problem with the part I posted. but, if these variables are to be used in other operations and reinitiated every time, I see a complex logic that goes on. Hence, my simple question was "is there way instead of NSMutableString' to do that?

Comment: We can't help you simplify your complex logic if you only show us your simple logic.  Edit your question to include the code that needs to be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

> It is becoming cumbersome with some complex arithmetic operations using this object.

That's because you're doing things in a cumbersome way. Try this instead:

```
digit = (int)sender.tag;
currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + digit;
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentNumber];
```

Don't try to derive the display string separately from the value that you're using for computation. The computation value, `currentNumber`, is like your data model -- it's the thing that your program is going to operate on. So instead of appending digits to the display string to try to cobble together the string to display, determine the string to display from the number you're working with (or going to work with). That way, if the user hits the <kbd>√</kbd> button, you can do something like:

```
currentNumber = sqrt(currentNumber);
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentNumber];
```

You probably *should* develop a more complete data model than just using a single numeric variable. You want a `CalculatorModel` class, or something like that, which you can give inputs when the user hits a key, and always get the current output. There's no generic version of that because every app does something different -- the model is a big part of what *you* bring to the party when you write an app.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. You gave the answer I was looking for. Removing the displayString variable simplified the logic for me. Thanks again.